# How to specify weight in GlanceModifier

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, glance

Jetpack Glance version 1.0.0-alpha03

I want to do the following

```
Row {
    Text(text = "Test text", modifier = GlanceModifier.weight(1f))
    Image(...)
}
```

However, it looks like there is no weight modifier for GlanceModifier?
If not what is the best way to get the same result?

Comment: This modifier is still not available in version 1.0.0-alpha04.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out how to make it work:

```
Row(modifier = GlanceModifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
    Text(text = "Test text", modifier = GlanceModifier.defaultWeight())
    Image(...)
}
```

Comment: That's correct. The defaultWeight modifier is what you need. It basically sets a weight of 1. There is no API so far to set different weights but that's normally not needed. With default weight should be enough for most of the use cases

Comment: I still would like to add different weights. For example I would like to make a row which would have 2 columns of 3:5 ratio. I don't think we have that API even as of today in Glance Modifier.