# How to use weight in GlanceModifier?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, glance-appwidget, glance

I am using Glance for the first time in my application I would like to use weight method for UI to be able to use it for all screen size's however GlanceModifier does not include weight method and Modifier from compose can not be used inside Widget implementation is there any work around? I have checked but can not find any solution.

Comment: This answer is still relevant : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72922735/how-to-specify-weight-in-glancemodifier

TL;DR; GlanceModifier.defaultWeight sets the weight to 1. There is no more general weight API at the moment.